# How to replace EC2 spot instance with on-demand instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have been working on a scenario where I need to have mixed (on-demand and spot) instances. I am very confused if AWS took back spot instance then how I can handle this? I actually want to replace that stopped spot instance with an on-demand instance in the given two minutes notice.
Is that even possible or not? If yes, please let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: It's not possible.  Also, note the two minutes notice is best effort, it might (and in my experience, sometimes is) zero minutes notice.  Generally, with spot instances, you must be prepared for them to be removed completely, and handle bringing up a new instance to replace whatever work is in progress.

Comment: Please note that you are not "replacing" an instance. Rather, you will be launching a new instance. (Hopefully you understand this, just mentioning it for future readers). An alternate approach is to use [Spot Fleet - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) that can do some of this work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just want to know that in spot fleet or ec2 fleet, what happened when the instance is interrupted by AWS? Will spot fleet automatically spin up a new on demand instance? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: I think it replaces the instance with another Spot instance. You see, instance shortages normally only affect one AZ and one instance type. Spot Fleet will spin-up another spot instance of the same type in another AZ, or a different type in the same AZ (depending on your settings). That way, it remains low-cost.

Comment: That now totally makes sense. Thanks. One more thing, can you suggest what should I use EC2 Fleet or Spot Fleet, if I have to spin up mixed type of instance like on-demand and spot. I think Ec2 Fleet will be best for me, right?